# WebKit .Net RaiseEvent/Click equivalent

Tags: .net, automation, webkit, click, raiseevent

I'm experimenting with the WebKit .Net component in an application. Usually with the standard WebBrowser component I can select an element by id and then raise an event on it using the RaiseEvent method or, for clicks, simply use the Click method. However, I can't seem to find similar functionality in the WebKit browser - how should I go about raising events and making automated clicks with it?

All help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has been a while since I asked this and I pretty much managed to figure this out myself after a while - there isn't an equivalent. You just have to use Microsoft's default WebBrowser component to do things like this.